# Wix hack needed to change video from dataset, by button click to a Lightbox

Tags: web, lightbox, velo

I have had success setting up a listing page displaying the data.  But, I would like to get the lightbox to change when I click on the button on the previous page to show the video change corresponding to the button click.   So, far it only picks up the 1st record both items listed.

Comment: As far as I know, Wix doesn't allow you to write arbitrary code to put into pages.  Everything has to be configured through their point/click/drag interface.  Given that, I don't see how this is a programming question that can be answered here.

Comment: They have a a DEV feature to add in Javascript, to their components.